# Change default version of Nano on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, terminal, console, nano

I've got nano 2.0.6 as default in my Mac OS X terminal when executing `nano`.
I've got nano 2.9.1 in `/usr/local/Cellar/nano/2.9.1/bin/nano`.

How do I change the default `nano`to version 2.9.1 in the terminal?

I'm running Mac OS X 10.13.1.

Answer (score 2):

[This another answer](https://superuser.com/a/1274746/432690) is good, especially as a temporary override. For the sake of completeness this is the main point of it:

> ```
> export PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/nano/2.9.1/bin:$PATH"
> ```

The problem is: if you need a permanent solution for multiple tools then with such a simple approach your `$PATH` will unnecessarily bloat.

This is how to avoid this (on Debian; the question is for Mac OS X but I believe the solution also applies or can be easily adapted). First create your own `bin/`:

```
mkdir ~/bin/
```

(Edit: on macOS, `~/Library/bin/` fits the home folder organization a bit better. I decided not to change my answer though, adapt this path to your needs.)

Next modify your `$PATH`:

```
PATH=~/bin:"$PATH"
```

(See *note 1* down below if you want to make it permanent.)

Then symlink the desired `nano` (and any other binary) to your custom `bin/`:

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/nano/2.9.1/bin/nano ~/bin/
```

(See *note 2* down below if you want to use this `nano` right away.)

This approach has the following advantages:

- your `$PATH` stays relatively short and clean;
- with `ls -l ~/bin/` you can easily tell which tools you do override with what; this is much better than analyzing a bloated `$PATH` which specifies directories; every directory may include many executables and you need to `ls` anyway to know them;
- removing a symlink, creating it anew is way easier than modifying `$PATH`, especially from within a script;
- you can also place your own scripts in `~/bin/`.

---

Note 1: in my Debian the `/etc/skel/.profile` includes the following code:

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

My `~/.profile` was created as a copy of `/etc/skel/.profile`, so the code is there from the very beginning. This means every new shell session adjusts its `$PATH` to include my private `bin/`; all I had to do was create the directory.

---

Note 2: while modifying `$PATH` in the middle of a session (e.g. to test my solution) keep in mind your shell may remember the old location of any executable it had already looked up according to the old `$PATH`. Common shells use [`hash`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1p/hash/) builtin to manage this. Use `hash -r` if needed.

If you customize `$PATH` at the very beginning of a shell session (like in `.profile`) then there's no such problem.

Comment: On macOS, ~/Library/bin fits the home folder organization a bit better. ~/Library is a hidden folder containing things that're accessed automatically (e.g. by inclusion in `$PATH`) rather than by manually selecting them (e.g. in an "Open" dialog).

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thank you. My answer now mentions this.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a symbolic link from `/usr/local/Cellar/nano/2.9.1/bin/nano`to `/usr/local/bin`

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/nano/2.9.1/bin/nano /usr/local/bin/nano
```

or you could create an alias.

```
alias nano=/usr/local/Cellar/nano/2.9.1/bin/nano
```

Comment: this won't work since MacOS will first look in /usr/bin/

Answer (score 1):

Seems:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/nano/2.9.1/bin:$PATH"
```

does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Could also add this to your .bashrc/.zshrc/etc

```
function nano {
    local nano_ver=$(l /usr/local/Cellar/nano/)
    /usr/local/Cellar/nano/$nano_ver/bin/nano $1
}
```

and a perfect function with syntax highlighting would be:

```
function nano {
    local nano_ver=$(l /usr/local/Cellar/nano/)
    if [ ! -f  ~/.nanorc ]; then
        touch ~/.nanorc
    else
        truncate -s 0 ~/.nanorc
    fi
    echo "include /usr/local/Cellar/nano/$nano_ver/share/nano/*.nanorc" >> ~/.nanorc
    /usr/local/Cellar/nano/$nano_ver/bin/nano $1
}
```

Comment: This worked for me after I changed the expression to use `ls` instead of `l`: `local nano_ver=$(ls /usr/local/Cellar/nano/)`.